# Login time out error for pyodbc connection string in kedro

Tags: sql-server, azure-pipelines, pyodbc, kedro

I'm trying to build up connection string in **kedro** for **SQLQueryDataset** to set the connection with MSSQL and Pyodbc in Azure Databricks but encountered with an error:

> (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Setting up connection string in credentials.yml file as
con:

```
mssql+pyodbc://${sql_username}:${sql_password}@{sql_server_name}/{database_name}?    driver=${Driver}&MARS_Connection=Yes&authentication=SqlPassword&TrustServerCertificate=Yes

Driver= ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+SERVER
```

Setting up connection string in credentials.yml file as
con:

```
mssql+pyodbc://${sql_username}:${sql_password}@{sql_server_name}/{database_name}?    driver=${Driver}&MARS_Connection=Yes&authentication=SqlPassword&TrustServerCertificate=Yes"

Driver= ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+SERVER
```

I'm accepting to read the SQL query and apply to the database mentioned in database_name. The SQL is as follows:

```sql
SELECT B.Practice,B.Enrollment_Start_Date, B.Enrollment_End_Date,
FROM [RBC].[RBC_Patients] B
```

Comment: Your SQL has a trailing comma (`,`) after `Enrollment_End_Date` that will cause an error.

Comment: Removed the comma but still error persists

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions that help me in the same problem:

1. (You use sql-server, then...) Change pyodbc to pymssql
2. Check if you dont't have any special characters in your password. If it is true, change the password or handle password with special characters by custom DB-connector class / custom dataset. It is possible with [create an DB-URL with sqlalchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#creating-urls-programmatically).
3. Make sure your password it not longer than 30 characters ;) (sqlalchemy limitation)
4. Execute the same query on the DB with other tool except kedro (eg. [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/)) to be sure your problem is in on this machine and the access to DB is granted.